# sed in script creating corrupt .tar.gz file

Tags: sed

I am installing a program which has a file "drown.bin" (Bourne shell script text executable). 
When I execute this file as part of the process, it gives error

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Below are file contents (pasted only Bash portion, rest is machine language)

```
dir_tmp=/tmp/.$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")
mkdir /$dir_tmp >/dev/null
sed -n -e '1,/^exit 0$/!p' $0 > "${dir_tmp}/.make-3000.tar.gz" 2>/dev/null
cd $dir_tmp >/dev/null
tar xvfz .make*.tar.gz >/dev/null
./.make
rm -rf $dir_tmp >/dev/null
exit 0
```

Can someone please advise what goes wrong in "sed" command to create a corrupted .tar.gz file. I already tried 3 systems with different CentOS versions.

Comment: what's the type of file $0? And why not using gtar or tar command instead of sed?

Comment: @almasshaikh the sed command is trying to extract the tar.gz content that follows the script. When that's done, tar is used to actually unpack the tar. Boils down to a "self-extract" procedure from a file containing both script + tar.gz data.

Comment: try removing the ">/dev/null" from the tar command to see all the output, may give more clues. Also try using the whole filename in the command rather than *, i.e. tar xvfz .make-3000.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `sed` command that fails, but the `tar` command.

This is a "self-extracting" tar file. The script that sits in front attempts to unpack the rest of the file, starting after the line `exit 0`. Likely the rest of the file is somehow corrupt.

If you downloaded it, try that again. If you copied it from somewhere else (especially FTP) make sure you used binary mode.

If that didn't work, what you could try to do:

1. copy the script-file to a file with extension .tgz, e.g. `cp drown.bin mycopy.tgz`
2. edit the copy, removing all script lines up to and including the `exit 0` line. The file now should be a pure tar.gz file.
3. on the command line, do a `tar tzvf mycopy.tgz` to see the contents. Try `tar xzvf mycopy.tgz` to actually unpack. This likely will fail with just the same error you got first, but at least now you can see the extracted content, at least the part that didn't fail.

Comment: The results are exactly you predicted. The file is definitely bad. I will get a new copy and will test. Thanks!